# Python Pydub AudioSegment laggy export

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pydub

I need to upload AudioSegment object to S3 after doing some editing. What I'm doing is to edit the audio, then *export* it and then send it to S3.

However, export to mp3 is taking like 2 seconds for 2 minutes song.

So, I'm just wondering if it's possible to send the file to S3 without export it. Note: I see there is raw_data, however, I need to be able to play the saved clip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay is caused by the transcoding step (converting the raw data to mp3). You can avoid that by exporting WAV files.

A WAV file is essentially just the raw data with some header information at the beginning so exporting with `format="wav"` will avoid the need to transcode, and should be significantly faster.

However, without any compression, the files will be larger (like 40MB instead of 5MB). You'll probably lose more than 2 seconds due to transferring 5 to 10 times more data over the network.

Some codecs are slower than others, so you may want to experiment with other encodings to strike a different speed/file size balance than mp3 and wav do (or you could try just using regular file compression like gzip, bz2, or a "zip" file on your wav output)